# OSM vector map and OSM data

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to create Android app using OSM vector map.

Is OSM vector map is rendered with OSM data? If yes how to implement in android?

Answer (score 2):

The OSM wik has a page about [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). It also lists several [libraries for Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles#Android), for example [mapsforge](http://mapsforge.org/).